# Why is it an "Unexpected token" error here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, jsonp

I'm trying to output a variable from this API my friend is currently working on. The API is fully open so authentication isn't required.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://profusum.se/js/jsonp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $.jsonp({
            url: "http://blackcab.didair.se/api/drivers",
            //callbackParameter: '',
            timeout: 45000,
            success: function (driversData, statusTwo) {
                $.each(driversData, function (i, data) {
                    var name = driversData.drivers[1].name;
                    document.write("<p> Namn: " + name);
                });
            },
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get this error when using Chrome Developer Tool:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :                               drivers:1
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: http://blackcab.didair.se/api/drivers&callback=hi is not returning jsonp. correct jsonp would be hi(the_object) not {the_object}

Comment: A valid JSONP response can be found here: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=cars&callback=hi

Comment: Also, beyond returning json instead of javascript, it returns `application/json` as content-type instead of `application/javascript` as it should be for jsonp.

Comment: Good call Joachim, keep forgetting about the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed with jQuery that the data returned is not JSONP and cannot be converted to it:

```
$.getJSON( "http://blackcab.didair.se/api/drivers?callback=?",
            //callbackParameter: '',
            function (data) {
            console.log("this is data:",data);
});
```

Results in:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
{"drivers":[{
```

The site returns JSON not JSONP. In order for another site to connect to blackcab.didair.se the blackcab.didair.se has to return JSONP or set a cors response header (look on wikipedia for cors and same origin policy).

At the moment blackcab.didair.se is returning JSON and that's not the same as JSONP